# escape all characters from list in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I want escape all characters from list.
In js it is:

```js
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

How I can do it in Java?

Comment: Do you mean to add "\" before each character? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a literal pattern from string you can use `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(String s)`.